# need to fetch each row in csv file and store in a dictionary

Tags: python, list, csv, dictionary, tuples

Hi all I have a csv file where I need to iterate each row of csv and then store in a dictionary with key and values,

The Key will be the header of the CSV

for example, I have one CSV name as csv_file_data:

```
    sno.    val-1   val-2
      1       200      20
      2        22      44
      3        56      32
      4        32      45
```

form this I need the following output:

```
    {'csv_file_data':[{'val-1':200,'val-2':20},{'val-1':22,'val-2':44},{'val-1':56,'val-2':32},{'val-1':32,'val-2':45}]}
```

Hi bro,

```
 data_dict=[{'csvfile1_data': [{'val-1': '0', 'val-2': '0'}, {'val-1': '0', 'val-2': '0'}]}, {'csvfile2_data': [{'val-3': '138', 'val-4': '0'}, {'val-3': '0', 'val-4': '0'}]}]

 input=('input_file' [{'val-1': '100', 'val-4': '1990'}, {'val-2': '90', 'val-1': '0.0'}])
```

so in this, I need to replace values present in input_file with 1st list

output I needed:

```
 data_dict=[{'csvfile1_data': [{'val-1': '100', 'val-2': '0'}, {'val-1': '0', 'val-2': '90'}]}, {'csvfile2_data': [{'val-3': '138', 'val-4': '1990'}, {'val-3': '0', 'val-4': '0'}]}]
```

Comment: Your output is a list type because you set output = [] that means you have a empty list.

Comment: why not simply use `csv.DictReader`?

Comment: @Module_art oohh ok so I need that list as a values and the csv_file_data as key

Comment: @buran I don't know how to use csv.DictReader, but thanks I will check this

Comment: `return {'csv_file_data':list_values}` ?

Comment: @Patrik there is zero value to adding another four spaces to what's already formatted as code, please stop proposing edits like that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
def get_data_csv(fn):

    mylist = []
    
    with open(fn, "r") as msg:
        for line in msg:
            mylist.append(line.strip())
        msg.close()
    
    mydict = {}
    mydict['csv_file_data'] = []
    
    headers = mylist[0].split()
    
    del mylist[0]
    
    for line in mylist:
        tmp_dict = {}
        tmp_dict[headers[1]] = int(line.split()[1])
        tmp_dict[headers[2]] = int(line.split()[2])
        mydict['csv_file_data'].append(tmp_dict)
    
    return mydict
```

You load your data in a list of lines `mylist.`

You declare your dictionary and `mydict['csv_file_data']` with an empty list in.

Then you get your headers from `mylist[0].split()`.

Since you do not need `mylist[0]` you del on it.

You read the others lines in `mylist`, split them and load them into a temporary dict with relevant key (header).

Then you append that `tmp_dict` to `mydict`.

And you get:

```
{'csv_file_data': [{'val-1': 200, 'val-2': 20}, {'val-1': 22, 'val-2': 44}, {'val-1': 56, 'val-2': 32}, {'val-1': 32, 'val-2': 45}]}
```

Comment: thanks but I got an error in this     tmp_dict[headers[1]] = line.split()[1]
IndexError: list index out of range

Comment: well I copied/pasted your data in my text editor and made it on it. Got no problem. Are your data the exact same than those you posted? What is your text editor? Are you space delimited as in your example?

Comment: I am using pycharma and the csv data is also different and large, that way I put an example of csv

Comment: Well if your csv has a given number of rows and columns, and if no values are missing, then it must work. Try maybe .split(",") or .split("\t") in case  your csv is delimited by comma or tab instead of space as in your example.

Comment: I have one more question, could you please help me :)

Comment: If not directly related, make another post :)

Comment: I will see just add "python" in the tags

Comment: I will be going to update my question at the last of this question is this fine?

Comment: hi. I think you should make a new post for this, as it is another kind of operation :)

Comment: yes you are right but I can't post a new question, I need to wait for 2 days after post previous question